# Encode multiple values to single long

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, encode, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to encode following numbers into single 64bit long in C#:

- up to 2048 (year) => 12 bits
- up to 16 (month) => 6 bits
- up to 32 (day) => 7 bits
- up to 32 (hour) => 7 bits
- other values of total 63 bits (including previous values)

Structure of the resulting number should contain encoded values with fixed bit sizes so I can easily decode it (for example decode month by taking 6 bits starting from 13th bit of the number, because first 12 bits are reserved for year).

I did not work with bitwise operations very often so far, so I'm a bit struggling with it and I came up with following code to do it:

```
private static long AddBitwise(long to, int toAdd, int startPosition, int maxLengthInBits)
{
    var filledNumber = (1 >> maxLengthInBits) | toAdd;
    to |= filledNumber << startPosition;
    return to;
}
```

Then I call it like this to encode all values:

```
private static long CalculateMaxBinary(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i)
{
    long result = 0;

    result = AddBitwise(result, a, 52, 12);
    result = AddBitwise(result, b, 47, 5);
    result = AddBitwise(result, c, 41, 6);
    result = AddBitwise(result, d, 35, 6);
    result = AddBitwise(result, e, 28, 7);
    result = AddBitwise(result, f, 23, 5);
    result = AddBitwise(result, g, 17, 6);
    result = AddBitwise(result, h, 9, 8);
    result = AddBitwise(result, i, 1, 8);

    return result;
}
```

However I must be doing something wrong or taking completely wrong approach, can someone show me an example of how to set specific fixed number of bits at specified position into number?

Comment: Can't help but point out that [DateTime](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,138) *is* a single unsigned 64-bit value. Decoding it is [already provided in the class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,754)

Comment: Yes, but I need to encode only part of the DateTime (for example no seconds and year only up to 2048) and I need to encode other values that have nothing to do with DateTime

Comment: `1 >> maxLengthInBits` -- what is this meant to do?

Comment: @LadislavBohm *why*? You'll only end up with a slow, error-prone class that probably takes more memory than simply creating a structure with the fields you want. That's because all this encoding/decoding will be a lot slower than simply accessing fields. The temporary values generated will result in memory waste.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I stated my reason in comment under the answer from Christopher.

Comment: If you're using bitwise operations, use `ulong` otherwise the top bit is going to give you some grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and actually easier than what you have tried. You do need to be careful to make the number a `long` *before* left-shifting it, otherwise bits can get lost or the number may be shifted by the wrong amount (remember that shift counts are taken modulo the size of the left operand) or both.

But all you need is to cast to `long`, shift left, and OR that into what you have:

```
private static long AddBitwise(long to, int toAdd, int pos)
{
    return to | ((long)toAdd << pos);
}
```

The size is not required here, but you could auto-update the position using the size:

```
private static long prependBitwise(long to, int value, ref int pos, int size)
{
    pos -= size;
    return to | ((long)value << pos);
}
```

Use like this:

```
int pos = 64;
long packed = 0;
packed = prependBitwise(packed, year, ref pos, 12);
packed = prependBitwise(packed, month, ref pos, 4);
packed = prependBitwise(packed, day, ref pos, 5);
// etc
```

By the way most of your bitfields are oversized. To represents day numbers in [1..31], only 5 bits are needed. 32 is not a real day, but even if it was that would still only require 6 bits, not 7.

There are other strategies, for example still packing "top field to bottom field" but shifting the packed long left as we go along, eventually leaving the bottom field in the bottom bits (rather than the top field in the top bits), just a different alignment:

```
private static long prependBitwise(long to, int value, int size)
{
    return (to << size) | value;
}
```

This is a bit nicer since it doesn't need that ugly by-ref `pos`, and has only 3 arguments like the first version (but without its weakness of enabling overlapping fields to be specified by accident), and also it tends to keep the resulting packed long smaller (lower values) if it is not completely filled.

Note that filling the top bit (aka "sign bit") is fine, you can treat it like a normal bit, but some care must be taken when *decoding* since some ways of extracting the topmost bitfield would enable it to have a negative value. Switching to `ulong` would prevent such surprises.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer which is the one actually answering my question even though in the end I will probably use different approach than encoding values into long. I finally have better understanding about bitwise operations and how to handle them correctly and in a safe way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I generally find it non-adviseable to encode values like that. The .NET Designers went through a lot of trouble so we would never have to deal with "how is it represented in memory" and from my native C++ Experience I think we should avoid that level.

Generally it is good enough to make a struct with a bunch of 8bit, 16bit and 32bit integers and leave it at that. You can only save that much by squeezing 9 7-bit values into 63 bit rather then just having 9 8-bit values (72 bit).
And often it costs you more code readability, memory and CPU time to de- and encode then this minimal saving (9 bit) is worth.

If 9 bit per instance even mater for memory constraints, it sounds like you should be changing some other part of the design so you do not need that much memory/that many instance to begin with. There is a high danger that you are stuck in a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you think this optimisation is the solution.

Comment: DateTime stores date and time as a single tick value. This is already being decoded to return month, year, day etc

Comment: I am thinking about this approach because I will be handling large amounts of data in database and I need to be able to determine uniqueness among those records. This single value of long would have a unique index on itself. I believe (hope) there is performance benefit compared to having index spread across like 4 columns in DB (some of the varchar)

Comment: @Christopher you are probably right about XY problem and I will rethink the problem from broader perspective, because this approach probably isnt what I want. Thanks

Comment: @LadislavBohm: There are dedicated "HashValue()" functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and interfaces. And a dedicated HashList collection. Sounds like that is more what you want.

Comment: @LadislavBohm: Generally I would keep filtering and the like to the DB query as far as possible. Most DBMS use the highly effective B+ Tree for indexes, wich speed up search/filtering dramatically. But for anything else, you can use the HashCode functions to make a "pre-filtering". It is a good "pre check" for unqiueness. If hte hashes do not match, they *can* not be equal. If they do match, you can do the detailed (and much more more intesive) checks on every field to verify.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this, you can resort to some bit-twiddling:

```
public static ulong SetBits(ulong value, int bitOffsetInOutput, int inputBits, int inputBitCount)
{
    ulong outputMask = (1ul << bitOffsetInOutput+inputBitCount) - (1ul << bitOffsetInOutput);
    ulong inputMask  = (1ul << inputBitCount) - 1ul;

    return (value & ~outputMask) | (((ulong)inputBits & inputMask) << bitOffsetInOutput);
}
```

This lets you set a specified range of bits in a given 64 bit number to the specified number of bits taken from a 32 bit number, without affecting any other bits in the 64-bit number.

Note that this won't set the highest bit - but you say that there are only 63 bits of data, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Test program:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ulong value = 0;

            value = SetBits(value, 8, 0b111111111111, 6);

            // Expected result = 11111100000000
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((long)value, 2)); 

            value = SetBits(value, 17, 0xFFFF, 7);

            // Expected result = 111111100011111100000000
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((long)value, 2));

            value = SetBits(value, 19, 0, 2);

            // Expected result = 111001100011111100000000
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((long)value, 2));
        }

        public static ulong SetBits(ulong value, int bitOffsetInOutput, int inputBits, int inputBitCount)
        {
            ulong outputMask = (1ul << bitOffsetInOutput+inputBitCount) - (1ul << bitOffsetInOutput);
            ulong inputMask  = (1ul << inputBitCount) - 1ul;

            return (value & ~outputMask) | (((ulong)inputBits & inputMask) << bitOffsetInOutput);
        }
    }
}
```